# Android button click text

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons and 6 textviews. I want that when any button is clicked(let's say button 2) then, the text of button 2 should go in the first textview and when another button is clicked(let's say button 4) then the text of button 4 should go in second textview. I don't know what to do for that. I have written code for that please give me some condition for this`package com.aswdc_wordcross;

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button[] buttons = new Button[4];
    TextView[] textViews = new TextView[6];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        buttons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        buttons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        buttons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
        buttons[3].setOnClickListener(this);

        textViews[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview1);
        textViews[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview2);
        textViews[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview3);
        textViews[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview4);
        textViews[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview5);
        textViews[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview6);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.Button1:
                break;

            case R.id.Button2:
                break;

            case R.id.Button3:
                break;

            case  R.id.Button4:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 Buttons and 6 TextViews, so it is unclear what you want.  
To set the text of a TextView you use its setText() method, like:

```
textViews[1].setText("something");
```

If you want the text of a Button to be displayed in a TextView:

```
textViews[1].setText(buttons[1].getText().toString());
```

So inside `onClick()`, implement the logic you want to apply at each case by using the above code like:

```
case R.id.Button2:
    textViews[X].setText(buttons[X].getText().toString());
    break;
```

**Edit**
If you want to set the text of the 1st `TextView` only, I guess this is `textViews[0]`, 
then you don't need the `switch` statement:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    textViews[0].setText(button.getText().toString());
}
```

**Edit2**
If you want to set sequentially the text of the `TextView`s

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
        if (textViews[i].getTag() == null) {
            textViews[i].setText(button.getText().toString());
            textViews[i].setTag("0");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't got the solution. I want that when any random button is clicked then the text of that random button should move in first textview. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Can u plz tell me the solution for that?

Comment: Can u also share the code for all other buttons also?

Comment: What do you mean? This works for any button clicked.

Comment: Yeah it works but  what  should I do for other textviews?

Comment: You are the one who knows your app's logic.

Comment: The logic is that when i press any random button then the text of that button should move to the first textview. After the button is clicked the text is  moved to the first textview. Now again the user clicks any random button and again the text of that random button goes to the second textview. I am making a word connect game. I guess you understood that.

Comment: And why do you have 4 Buttons and 6 TextViews? Also what happens when the user clicks  7 times random buttons?

Comment: When the user clicks any random button the text should go to first textview and once the text is moved to the first textview it will not be edited. And again the user clicks the random button and the text moves to the second textview and again that text in second textview will not be edited. Then the other random click text should move to third textview. Like that it continues....

Comment: And what happens when all textviews have been set to a button's text and the user clicks again a button?

Comment: The words will be formed in the textview and if the word is correct then the green light will be shown in the textview and if it is wrong then red color will be shown.

Comment: @BhavdipDave you must click the checkmark at the left of my answer